# How to shuffle the letters of a word in php

Tags: php, random, shuffle, words, anagram

I saw on some SO posts that to shuffle arrays, you would use php's `shuffle($array);`.

However, my problem is that I generate a randomn word from the dictionary (which I know how to do and is working) and then shuffle the letters randomnly into an anagram.

So basically - the word `random` would go to `adrmon` or something similar, but it shuffles the letters in the word randomnly.

How can I do this in php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function shuffleWord($word) {

    $wordArray = str_split($word);
    shuffle($wordArray);
    return implode('',$wordArray);
}

$word = 'random';
$anagram = shuffleWord($word);
```

Answer (score 0):

[From PHP manual - str_shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php)

You could user str_shuffle function in PHP.